# My android will not charge nor turn on

Tags: sony-xperia

My sony xperia tx lt29i wouldnt charge yesterday. So i took the battery out for a few minutes and then i placed it back in and it started to charge until it was full. The next day the battery died (cause i was playing on it) and i put it on again, but wouldnt charge. Now it wont turn on, ive tried taking the battery out for a whole day and came back from school and wouldnt charge. Some people say that the problem is the motherboard?is it, or is it something else?

Comment: Try putting in a new battery

Answer (score 0):

### It depends

As you said that you are playing with the battery,

**If the battery is damaged, it may produce power with different voltage. As you tried putting and turning the phone on using that battery, the over voltage may damaged your phone**

Else,

**The battery is dead. You can put a new battery and start using it.**